# How do I create triangles like this?

Tags: css

Hello I would like to know how to create these little triangles on top of the footer in this template : http://demo.themezilla.com/classica/portfolio/redwood-publishing/.
I looked  CSS in the source I found this :

```
border-top: 1px solid # e0e0e0
```

but it does not work.

Comment: They have used image for the footer

Comment: I don't even know how should I flag this question, but I know it doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an [image](https://web.archive.org/web/20140530080304if_/http://turbo.themezilla.com/classica/wp-content/themes/classica/images/bg-foot.gif)!!!

You forgot to see this:

```
#footer-container {
  background: url(images/bg-foot.gif) left top repeat-x #f5f5f5;
  margin: 80px 0 0 0;
}
```

Just saying, if you wanna get it, you need this CSS:

```
.footer {
  background: url("http://turbo.themezilla.com/classica/wp-content/themes/classica/images/bg-foot.gif") left top repeat-x #f5f5f5;
}
```

But **do not** hotlink the image without their permission. The image looks this way:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/F5RVR/